# what is the best way to select option when option is an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to select option when option is an object?

During changing selected value I need to get selected option object

example https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-select-object-ssib9

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(options[0]);

  return (
    <select
      value={value}
      onChange={event => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      }}
    >
      {options.map(option => {
        return <option value={option}>{option.label}</option>;
      })}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: i have added the post below with snippet as well as demo link which you provided earlier in your question, please verify that, hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59541734/5783700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the state to be an object and not the *select*'s *value*, if so then try the following:

```
const [option, setOption] = useState(options[0]);

function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const option = options.find(o => o.value === parseInt(value, 10));
    if(option)
      setOption(option); // object
}

...

<select
  value={option.value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
      {options.map(option => <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>)}
</select>
```

**Demo**:

[image: Edit ST-OF select object]

Comment: I think it is one posible solution

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to use option.value to access the value of selected value

```
{options.map(option => {
    return <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>;
 })
}
```

Comment: I need object and not only value from selected object

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working demo which I have created:

https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-select-object-ytohv

And you will get your selected option object in state `value`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `handleChange` method there and then you'll get the selected value easily. I'm printing the selected value in console. Please check this [working-demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-select-object-pwm3i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Here is the code, if you are interested in.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const options = [...Array(10).keys()].map(item => {
  return {
    value: item,
    label: `label ${item}`
  };
});

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(options[0]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value); // This is the selected value
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={e => handleChange(e)}>
      {options.map(option => {
        return <option value={option.label}>{option.label}</option>;
      })}
    </select>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added/updated the snippet based on your requirement, now you can pass or select whole object rather selecting single value in dropdown using **HOOK** concept in react.

Please see [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-select-object-j4bgr)

```js
const options = [...Array(10).keys()].map(item => {
    return {
      value: item,
      label: `label ${item}`
    };
});

function App() {
   const [selectedValue, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
   
   {console.log("SELECTED OPTION OBJECT")}
   {console.log(selectedValue)}
   
   return (
           <select onChange={event => { setValue(JSON.parse(event.target.value)); }}>
               {options.map((option, index) => {
                   return (<option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(option)}>{option.label}</option>);
               })}
           </select>
   );
 }
 
 const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How can I get selected option object?

Comment: @fetchenko Please verify https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-select-object-j4bgr

Comment: I have passed an object as a value and update the state of selected value using the hook. so you can get the value of selected option as an object.